# Running a streaming word count on FlinkCluster using Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to run the modified `WindowedWordCount(NewWordCount)` example using beam on the local `flink` cluster. Now I want it to read the data continuously from the local directory specified, do the `wordcount` based on window and then output single file for each window. The window is time-based (1 min). And for the output, the trigger could be time-based or record based.
I am using 
Flink 1.7
Beam 2.11

NewWordCount is the Code i have tried. The command I am using is:

```
mvn compile exec:java -D exec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.NewWordCount -D exec.args="--runner=FlinkRunner --flinkMaster=localhost --filesToStage=.\target\word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar --inputFile='<dir path>\input\*' --output='<dir path>\output_streaming\count' --streaming=true --parallelism=1" -P flink-runner
```

This works fine for the files in the directory. It reads all the files computes the output and creates two output files with word count. The pipeline keeps on running, but it does not read the new file put in the directory(as I understand streaming should). Neither is the output continuous, or window based even in the case of huge input

```
public static class DefaultToMinTimestampPlusOneHour implements DefaultValueFactory<Long> {
  @Override
  public Long create(PipelineOptions options) {
    return options.as(Options.class).getMinTimestampMillis()
      + Duration.standardHours(1).getMillis();
  }
}

...

static void runWindowedWordCount(Options options) throws IOException {
  final String output = options.getOutput();
  final Instant minTimestamp = new Instant(options.getMinTimestampMillis());
  final Instant maxTimestamp = new Instant(options.getMaxTimestampMillis());

  Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    pipeline
        .apply(ParDo.of(new AddTimestampFn(minTimestamp, maxTimestamp)))
        .apply(Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                                      .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                      .withEarlyFirings(
                                          AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                              .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                                      .withLateFirings(
                                          AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                              .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(2))))
                              .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                              .accumulatingFiredPanes())
        .apply(new WordCount.CountWords())
        .apply(MapElements.via(new WordCount.FormatAsTextFn()))
        .apply(new WriteOneFilePerWindow(output, options.getNumShards()));

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

  runWindowedWordCount(options);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what input transform you use since I can't find the input transform in your example code. If you want a continuous input, you should use an unbounded source. For `TextIO`, [`watchForNewFiles`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html#watchForNewFiles-org.joda.time.Duration-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Watch.Growth.TerminationCondition-) does the work.